# Rewrite rule to redirect a URI without a query param after appending a query param

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, aem

I need to check if a UIRI from a folder contains any query param and if not, add the query param and redirect the uri in browser also using Apache rewrite rule. For this all url's starting with `/abc/def/xyz/` the url should be appended with `?v=2`, if not already having a query param

For example, `/abc/def/xyz/folder/test.pdf` should become `/abc/def/xyz/folder/test.pdf?v=2`

But `/abc/def/xyz/folder1/test.pdf?v=3` should be left untouched.

I was able to add the query param using below but it causes infinite redirects. Thats why I need the selective redirect

```
RewriteRule ^abc/def/xyz/(.*) /abc/def/xyz/$1?v=2 [L,R=301]
```

the below does not redirect the browser URL to the new URI with the query param:

```
RewriteRule ^abc/def/xyz/(.*) /abc/def/xyz/$1?v=2 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to check for Query Strings. I guess the following should do the trick. If there is a query String available, it would skip the rule. Else, it would append the query string `v=2`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^abc/def/xyz/(.*)$ /abc/def/xyz/$1?v=2 [L, R=301]
```

Hope it helps.